# How to select multiple file types with glob matching in git

Tags: git, glob

I have the following:

```
$ tree
.
├── bar
│   ├── foo.js
│   ├── foo.herp
│   ├── foo.derp
│   └── foo.py
├── bar.herp
└── baz.py
```

I want to use the following

`git ls-files -- {}` where `{}` is some sort of glob pattern

and I want it to return

```
bar/foo.js
bar/foo.py
baz.py
```

Comment: What's wrong with `*`?

Comment: @Anthony what are you trying to do? `git ls-files` already returns file paths in the format that you gave an example of.

Comment: Ah I'll update the question.  This was late at night and I had forgotten to indicate I only want js and py and not anything else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide any number of glob expressions after ls-files:

```
git ls-files -- '*.js' '*.py'
```

Answer (score 2):

Nope. As of git version 2.20.1

```
git ls-files -- '**/*.js' '**/*.py'
```

Will return no files

```
git ls-files -- '**/*.js'
```

Will return all .js files in the repo